Systemd-boot: where loader parameters are stored?
I've installed Arch-linux with archinstall, choosing systemd-boot as the bootloader and with full-disk encryption.
Lots of manuals refers to file /boot/loader/entries/arch.conf (or similar one), but my folder /boot/loader/entries is empty and file /boot/loader/loader.conf have only one line: timeout 3.
Where are other boot parameters stored?

archinstall is not recommended for this reason, because you don't know what/where to find what you want

When I installed Arch manually I think I had to create the files in …/entries/ myself. In an answer to another question I shared the contents of my config here  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414423/systemd-boot-install-failure/1416077#1416077 You shouldn’t need a ucode line now because that is handled differently now. You will need your own UUID for your root partition

There is an example of the loader file in this wiki entry https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd-boot
